# How do I pass three objects to a function that expects only two?

Tags: javascript, function, object, handlebars.js, gulp

I have the following function in my javascript. It expects two objects; one containing template variables and one containing options:

`handlebars(variables, options)`

However, I have *two* objects containing template variables (`var1` and `var2`) instead of one (`variables`), and want to pass them both to the handlebars function. How do I do that?

---

P.s.: I have tried passing them like so `handlebars(var1, var2, options)`, but then handlebars takes `var2` for the `options` object and errors out.

I've also tried `handlebars([var1,var2], options)` but that doesn't work either. Did I mention I'm a total noob at this? How can I pass all three objects to the function in the way it expects?

Comment: You'd probably have to merge your data containers in a way that your template understands. How does the template look like?

Comment: the best thing here would be to refactor your code - write it in a way that your template variables are in a single object, or change your function to accept three arguments if required.

Comment: @m90, the error I get is from the handlebars function not understanding the objects it's being passed. The template will simply ignore any tags it doesn't recognise.

Comment: @jammypeach, Yeah I agree, problem is I'm using prefabricated gulp functions that I can't change easily. I'll include some more of the surrounding syntax for context, I hope it won't make the question too confusing.

Comment: @Sam OK, that rules out changing the function, so I'd look at how you can rewrite your code so you always have a single object. Another (hacky) way around it would be to write a function that accepts three arguments, merges two, then calls handlebars() with the modified arguments. But refactor is the best move I feel.

Comment: @Sam Well, the constraints are that you will only be able to render ONE set of data against your template (and any other template) so you'll somehow have to make your data fit into ONE set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably what you want to do is to have one object that has all the properties of both `var1` and `var2`. This is not an uncommon requirement, and various Javascript libraries support it, e.g. jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend) or Underscore.js's [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend).

It's also not too hard to do with native Javascript, which saves you from having to install a heavy library for one simple bit of functionality:

```
var combined = {},
    key;

for (key in var1) {
    if (var1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        combined[key] = var1[key];
    }
}

for (key in var2) {
    if (var2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        combined[key] = var2[key];
    }
}
```

You can then call `handlebars(combined, options)`.

Comment: This is what I did in the end. The other solutions are fine as well for what I can tell, so others might want to try the other solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to make a single object containing the contents of both `var1` and `var2`.  If they are plain old JavaScript objects and you have jQuery, you can do this:

```
var variables = $.extend({}, var1, var2);
handlebars(variables, options)
```

Comment: Can I do it without jquery too, in regular javascript? I don't know if I can use jquery in gulp..

Comment: @Sam: Handlebars and Gulp are fine with jQuery, don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

If a function expects certain parameters, you cannot use it with others (the number of them and the type). You will have to fit to its requirements.

If `var1` and `var2` are objects as the following ones:

```
var properties={
    prop1: "a",
    propr2: "b"
}

var properties2={
    prop3: "aa",
    prop4: "bb"
}
```

You can mix them in one variable (in this example the join is done in p1, so if a property exists in both objects, the p2 one remains):

```
function join(p1, p2) {
    for (var name in p2) {
        if (var1.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            p1[name]=p2[name];
        }
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, an `extend` function is the best solution for this problem.
However, often you don't want to include underscore, lodash or jquery just for one function.
The solution? Just write it yourself. It's not hard to do.
Here's an example for a shallow extend:

```
var extend = function () {
    // Get array of objects to be used as a source
    var sourceObjects = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // Iterate over all objects sequentially and copy their properties
    // over to the target object (the first argument).
    // That way the properties are copied over from the left to the right
    var result = sourceObjects.reduce(function (target, source) {
        for (key in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                target[key] = source[key];
            }
        }
        return target;
    }, arguments[0]); // the first argument is the target
    return result;
}

extend({}, {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'}, {foo: 'baz'}, {some: 'more', more: 'data'}, {some: 'less'} )
>> Object {foo: "baz", bar: "foo", some: "less", more: "data"}
```